# syntax of gam longitudinal dataset

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I would like to have some help on gam syntax in R. My question includes whether I am thinking about an appropriate model.

I have a longitudinal data-set in which participants can have a different number of follow-ups, so from 1 to 3 observation variables (brain region volume) are available for each participant. I would like to check the effect of age on this observation variable and because I have some reasons to believe that the relationship between my two variables isn't linear, I took interest in generalized additive models. So far, I built this model

`gam(data = df.data, obs ~ s(age) + gender + education + s(subject, age, bs = "re"), method = "REML")`

but I am not sure if this is a good way to model the cross-sectional and longitudinal effect of age on my variable of interest. Especially is this `s(subject, age, bs = "re")`  the way to model a random slope for each participant and does that makes sense?

Answer (score 3):

Your model:

```
gam(data = df.data, obs ~ s(age) + gender + education + s(subject, age, bs = "re"), 
    method = "REML")
```

would specify a global smooth of `age`, plus random slopes (i.e. linear effects) of `age` by subjects. You might want to add random intercepts to that model also: `+ s(subject, bs = 're')`.

If you assume the `age` effect is non-linear, you might want to use random *smooths* of `age` in your model. Then you have a couple of options

1. do you want a global smoother?
2. do you want each random smooth to have the same smoothness parameter (wiggliness)?

Colleagues and I outlined these models in detail in a recent paper (Pedersen et al 2019). Briefly, not covering all options, you could have random smooths via:

```
gam(obs ~ gender + education + s(age, subject, bs = "fs"), 
    data = df.data, method = "REML")
```

wherein all the subject specific smooths of `age` share the same degree of wiggliness (the same smoothness parameter). A global smooth plus random smooths would be given by

```
gam(obs ~ gender + education + s(age) + s(age, subject, bs = "fs"), 
    data = df.data, method = "REML")
```

If you want each subject to have different smoothness parameters (different wigglinesses) then two models above might become:

```
gam(obs ~ subject + gender + education + s(age, by = subject), 
    data = df.data, method = "REML")
```

and

```
gam(obs ~ subject + gender + education + s(age) + s(age, by = subject, m = 1), 
    data = df.data, method = "REML")
```

where I have added a fixed, parametric `subject` effect as factor `by` smooths are centred about the model intercept. And in the second `by` model I added `m = 1` so that we penalised deviations from the global smooth.

Which you want will depend on how you want to model the smooth effects. If you want to predict for `subject`s not in the data set, then you'll need a global smooth, for example.

### References

Pedersen, E.J., Miller, D.L., Simpson, G.L., Ross, N., 2019. Hierarchical generalized additive models in ecology: an introduction with mgcv. PeerJ 7, e6876. https://doi.org/10.7717/peerj.6876

Comment: Thank you @Reinstate Monica - G. Simpson for this very detailled help and the usefull ressource. I think I will go with a GS model (single common smoother plus group-level smoothers that have the same wiggliness) and use this syntax `gam(obs ~ gender + education + s(age) + s(age, subject, bs = "fs"), data = df.data, method = "REML")`. Besides, I am not sure to perfectly get the difference between `s(age, subject, bs = "fs")` and `s(subject, age, bs = "re") + s(subject, bs = 're')`, the second does'nt allow for random smooth within non linear effect ?.

Comment: Also, does the order of predictors matter in gam syntax as it could in lmer using `anova()` ?

Comment: I've tried to run this model `gam(obs ~ gender + education + s(age) + s(age, subject, bs = "fs"), data = df.data, method = "REML")` but it seems that I do not have enought observations in my dataset. I've also tried this `gam(obs ~ gender + education + s(age, bs ="cr", k=3) + s(age, subject, bs = "fs", k=3), data = df.data, method = "REML")` in order to decrease k and use natural cubic spline but it doesn't change the output. Do you know any solution to handle this problem ? Thanks

Comment: If you don't have enough data to use random smooths, use your model but also with `+ s(subject, bs = 're')` to add the subject random intercepts. No, order shouldn't matter for `anova.gam()` when you give it a single model; the effects are more like Type III SSQs or what `drop1()` gives you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already tried this and it does not work either. I guess I will go with the global smooth and a random intercept. Anyway, thank you for enlightening me.

Comment: You can fit the random slopes and intercepts more efficiently using the `gamm4::gamm4()` function which uses *mgcv* smooths. With that model you'll only pay 3 parameter price for fitting random slopes and intercepts. `gamm4(obs ~ gender + education + s(age), random = ~ (age|subject), data = df.data, method = 'REML')`

Comment: I figured out that the model works using `gamm` function like this `gamm(obs ~ gender + education + s(age) + s(age, subject, bs = "fs"), data = df.data, method = "REML")`. The summary is a bit different, I don't have the deviance explained and have NA values for the random smooth (maybe because some participants only have one time point)

Comment: Thank you for your last response I just saw it  when posting my last comment, I will have a look on this

Comment: It is advisable to check the variogram from these models to see if they properly capture the within-person correlation pattern.  In some cases it's better to not use random effects an instead to model serial correlation in a more direct way.