# Is my GAM modeling longitudinal change appropriately?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, gamm4

My data includes the following:

- `Y` which is a physiological measure
- `Age` continuous
- `Gender` factor, `Male` or `Female`
- `Timepoint` One for each year of study visit: `1,2,3,4`
- `subject` each unique subject

Model aim:

- To identify longitudinal changes of `Y` across `Timepoints`, for each `subject` between `Gender`

  - I am assuming a random slope and intercept is appropriate as each `subject` will have a different physiological change between `Timepoints`
- I am also trying to use `gratia::smooth_estimates` to plot the smooth term for `age` between `Gender`

Model:

```
m1 <- gam(Y ~ subject + Gender + s(age, by = subject) + s(Age, by = Gender, bs = 'fs') + s(Timepoint, subject, bs ='fs') +  s(subject, bs = "re") , 
    data = DF,
    method = "REML")
```

However, this does not work,

`Error in smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) :  A term has fewer unique covariate combinations than specified maximum degrees of freedom`

So I have to use:

```
m1.reduced <- gam(Y ~ Gender + s(Age, by = Gender, bs = 'fs') + s(subject, bs = "re"),
          method = "REML", 
          data = DF_y)
```

Or I can also use gamm4 (which works with the plot below, though I am not sure if it is appropriately modeling what I am intending:

```
m2 <- gamm4(Y ~ s(Age, by = Gender, bs = 'fs') + Gender+ Timepoint,
                     random = ~ (1 + Timepoint | subject),
                     data = DF)
```

Plot:

```
sm <- smooth_estimates(m1) %>% 
  add_confint()

ggplot(data = sm, aes(y = est, x = Age)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_ci, ymax = upper_ci, fill = Gender),
                alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Gender),  size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(data = DF, aes(Age, Y, color = Gender), alpha = .25) +
  geom_line(data = DF, aes(Age, Y, group = subject), alpha = 0.25) +
  ylab("Partial effect") +
  xlab("Age"))
```

I am trying to replicate a plot like this ([source](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41380-019-0360-1#Sec2)): where each color is a gender and the predicted longitudinal trajectory is plotted across age.

[image: plot]

This is my model 2 (`gamm4`) plot that is providing what I want.

However, **is my `gam` model modeling and plotting longitudinal change correctly**?
[image: m2]

sample data:

```
structure(list(subject= c(33714L, 35377L, 40556L, 40798L, 40800L, 
40815L, 50848L, 52183L, 52461L, 53320L, 53873L, 54206L, 54581L, 
55122L, 55267L, 55462L, 55612L, 55920L, 56022L, 56307L, 56420L, 
56679L, 57405L, 57480L, 57725L, 57809L, 58004L, 58215L, 58229L, 
59326L, 59327L, 59865L, 60099L, 60100L, 60280L, 60384L, 60429L, 
60493L, 60503L, 60603L, 60664L, 60846L, 61415L, 61749L, 61883L, 
62081L, 62983L, 63327L, 63329L, 64418L, 64507L, 64596L, 65178L, 
65250L, 65802L, 65975L, 65978L, 66396L, 66572L, 66589L, 74034L, 
74427L, 74607L, 74952L, 75732L, 76574L, 76595L, 76755L, 76759L, 
77203L, 77453L, 77668L, 81064L, 81065L, 33714L, 35377L, 40556L, 
40798L, 40800L, 40815L, 50848L, 52183L, 52461L, 53320L, 53873L, 
54206L, 54581L, 55122L, 55267L, 55462L, 55612L, 55920L, 56022L, 
56307L, 56420L, 56679L, 57405L, 57480L, 57725L, 57809L, 58004L, 
58215L, 58229L, 59326L, 59327L, 59865L, 60099L, 60100L, 60280L, 
60384L, 60429L, 60493L, 60503L, 60603L, 60664L, 60846L, 61415L, 
61749L, 61883L, 62081L, 62983L, 63327L, 63329L, 64418L, 64507L, 
64596L, 65178L, 65250L, 65802L, 65975L, 65978L, 66396L, 66572L, 
66589L, 74034L, 74427L, 74607L, 74952L, 75732L, 76574L, 76595L, 
76755L, 76759L, 77203L, 77453L, 77668L, 81064L, 81065L, 33714L, 
35377L, 40556L, 40798L, 40800L, 40815L, 50848L, 52183L, 52461L, 
53320L, 53873L, 54206L, 54581L, 55122L, 55267L, 55462L, 55612L, 
55920L, 56022L, 56307L, 56420L, 56679L, 57405L, 57480L, 57725L, 
57809L, 58004L, 58215L, 58229L, 59326L, 59327L, 59865L, 60099L, 
60100L, 60280L, 60384L, 60429L, 60493L, 60503L, 60603L, 60664L, 
60846L, 61415L, 61749L, 61883L, 62081L, 62983L, 63327L, 63329L, 
64418L, 64507L, 64596L, 65178L, 65250L, 65802L, 65975L, 65978L, 
66396L, 66572L, 66589L, 74034L, 74427L, 74607L, 74952L, 75732L, 
76574L, 76595L, 76755L, 76759L, 77203L, 77453L, 77668L, 81064L, 
81065L), Gender = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Male", "Female"), class = "factor"), 
    Age = c(15L, 15L, 9L, 11L, 16L, 9L, 16L, 16L, 14L, 8L, 6L, 
    14L, 10L, 15L, 13L, 15L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 10L, 
    7L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 15L, 8L, 11L, 14L, 12L, 10L, 16L, 12L, 10L, 
    6L, 13L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 10L, 13L, 14L, 12L, 17L, 9L, 12L, 
    11L, 10L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 14L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 10L, 
    12L, 9L, 9L, 16L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 13L, 15L, 13L, 13L, 8L, 
    11L, 16L, 16L, 11L, 13L, 18L, 10L, 18L, 18L, 15L, 10L, 8L, 
    15L, 12L, 16L, 14L, 16L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 14L, 
    12L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 16L, 9L, 13L, 16L, 13L, 12L, 18L, 13L, 
    11L, 8L, 14L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 11L, 14L, 15L, 14L, 18L, 11L, 
    14L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 11L, 11L, 15L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 
    11L, 13L, 10L, 11L, 18L, 11L, 15L, 16L, 14L, 17L, 14L, 14L, 
    9L, 12L, 18L, 18L, 12L, 14L, 19L, 11L, 19L, 19L, 16L, 11L, 
    9L, 17L, 13L, 18L, 16L, 18L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 
    16L, 13L, 9L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 17L, 11L, 14L, 17L, 14L, 13L, 
    19L, 15L, 12L, 9L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 15L, 
    20L, 12L, 15L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 16L, 19L, 18L, 16L, 
    16L, 15L, 12L, 14L, 11L, 11L, 19L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 15L, 18L, 
    15L, 15L, 10L, 13L), Y= c(-3.91040964443843, -4.1357309415226, 
    -3.15711439697149, -5.3057953682613, -5.64125379300701, -5.14501797062188, 
    0.244858660867345, 0.0760011434854038, -1.38050716781916, 
    -0.765398953185992, -1.47720169386702, -1.64309892713909, 
    -0.396819316883117, -1.36975793945299, -1.80785572309015, 
    -0.401914887891913, -0.811404680008261, -2.4492910546021, 
    -0.620903118150862, -1.10304119407832, -0.683772758549858, 
    -1.47159656575735, -0.823876696667884, 0.229547683217108, 
    -1.91347963071532, -1.05594355918274, -2.37962731952471, 
    -1.34893889218848, -0.385827442278431, -0.980092345023242, 
    -0.181058281596406, -0.832975930612162, -1.9959308225624, 
    -0.12787022611412, -0.205371434695515, -0.609353157197594, 
    -0.477183751078979, -1.53245224237668, -0.137187841673061, 
    -1.11978378453579, -1.38506891710323, -0.665622819909006, 
    -0.858065551674517, -0.935493966384356, -0.444790478237349, 
    -0.0888284463372063, 0.793433276899957, -1.37118955226023, 
    -1.27752810419379, 0.571630350274245, 0.38391922015976, -0.585743678190174, 
    -0.639562613892594, 0.637702921021628, 1.02283103079116, 
    0.509051885361466, 0.256796855802238, -0.827467860997893, 
    1.25436407158129, 0.797121499725372, -1.46470541258355, 0.72639012119852, 
    -1.77912640845008, 1.31912635264069, 0.135328148802092, -0.522413009938002, 
    0.680529982119362, 0.068624697834574, -0.598312753345204, 
    0.141370040141094, -0.392378890718311, 1.88269650621348, 
    -3.0968410713246, -0.0622101539722123, -4.1452184094485, 
    -0.954638754603117, -0.106347504757922, -0.716821176235476, 
    0.33910245990621, -1.65370256776216, 0.666505029533247, 1.11178514183042, 
    0.0370564222038934, 0.0466166840013479, -0.557572449898689, 
    -0.961796818639283, 0.936133529770083, -0.283139554139275, 
    -0.111006312537392, 0.655416096433155, 0.253351279215336, 
    -1.27117077274472, 0.821677299062997, 1.30061244464207, -0.571112110007776, 
    -0.978927643078376, -0.0939968112175565, 1.01351341523222, 
    -0.482667556069396, 0.416191169882131, -1.13218300732386, 
    0.0109719515636322, 0.570902411558704, 0.251628490921888, 
    0.757376045856767, -0.286245425992256, -0.850640576775985, 
    0.323694423760568, 0.33667599752107, 0.489882832518856, 0.0192219236731108, 
    -0.267852841112888, 1.81167395220041, -0.0196014744891418, 
    -0.0975879755475657, 1.11193072957353, 1.43135023795345, 
    -0.0901872652728838, 0.562191411596049, 0.0591857591563773, 
    1.10166679368438, -0.140293713526042, 0.0486791770287176, 
    0.34512008662136, 0.818328780971503, -0.238419852381131, 
    -0.368114266866903, 1.03486628422146, 0.539091489689507, 
    -0.233227222876931, -0.351614322647946, -0.108579850152251, 
    1.42892377556831, 0.96726504217144, -0.436055213650844, 0.565831105173759, 
    -1.54960733143962, 1.100259445501, -0.614861226811863, -0.361659876922429, 
    1.40706134947819, -0.552573937385301, 0.105482661464863, 
    -0.374326010572864, -0.0292830594058542, 1.98545718822419, 
    -1.19221368673224, 0.760991474810628, -0.539568099000947, 
    -0.0739542319162944, 0.34373700306183, 0.053071073945822, 
    0.0606901658351647, -0.211219209043705, 0.216590374080456, 
    1.00007081361854, -0.495649129829898, 0.0867746364754286, 
    -1.67723925289802, -0.826836980777755, 1.18863120556783, 
    -0.795681203752549, -0.650869928607352, 0.333545861044237, 
    0.63103014946249, -1.75748236397463, -0.118601139802882, 
    1.51474775013074, 0.132537717059181, -0.677973513449372, 
    0.467947612557183, 1.56786301174147, -0.118528345931329, 
    0.554596584330558, -0.59224659738235, -0.543498968064875, 
    -0.380440695783417, 0.0643541240367275, -0.210830975062082, 
    0.503471021875644, -0.660672836643319, 1.50676468888363, 
    0.780839937121078, -0.116635705270918, -0.240385286913095, 
    0.00044110481212036, 1.4571920623552, -0.350401091455376, 
    0.0850033189342734, 0.197882349091022, 0.726511444317778, 
    -0.331741595713643, 0.837497833814114, 0.609264781867777, 
    0.532151807268005, 0.65446977610295, -0.581909867621652, 
    0.322942220421174, 1.52993740466172, -0.264455793773691, 
    -0.0568476721010507, 1.05299195823846, 0.915435805624833, 
    0.297609953120304, -0.114257772133482, 0.248013061968027, 
    1.64822744593733, 1.26800079018578, -0.0459528559917708, 
    0.720784993088846, -1.05679282101754, 1.38345187047077, -0.64414862780051, 
    -1.25411274217718, 0.177548594303543, -0.257734492966852, 
    -0.818028922319694, 0.409736779937656, -0.216411838547905, 
    1.32536236097051, -0.500938817829506, 0.803770006660658), 
    Timepoint= c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
    3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 
    3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 
    4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 
-222L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: In what sense is it not working? Apart from the obvious problem that there is no way that figure can be produced using `smooth_estimates()` as smooths in {mgcv} are (typically) centred and hence will span positive and negative values. Is that also a typo: `gender` vs `by = Gender`?

Comment: I updated the question. The original plot is just a sample, sorry for the confusion, my plot does span negative values. I don't think the `by = gender` is a typo, but maybe an inaccuracy in the model?

Comment: You don't have `gender` in your dataset, only `Gender` so the code will produce an error if you're using `gender` in the formula.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I thought you were asking about the `by` function, not the spelling, yes that's a typo, I will fix that

Comment: You are assuming a compound symmetric correlation structure, which ignores the forward flow of time.   Think about using a serial correlation structure instead, and using a Markov process or generalized least squares.

Comment: @FrankHarrell is this possible with `gam`, using something like `corAR1(form = ~ Timepoint)`?

Comment: @CanyonView for `gamm()` *only* you can use use `corAR1()` or `corARMA()` *if* your data are sampled regularly in time. If they aren't you can use `corCAR1()`. For `gam()` and `gamm4::gamm4()` you are out of luck. You could use `bam()` with *known* (or a priori estimated outside `bam()`) value of $\rho$ for an AR(1) process in the residuals.

Comment: I'm not sure that I need `corAR1`. My data is similar to this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/459200/syntax-of-gam-longitudinal-dataset I am just confused why timepoint is not included that model.

Comment: Also, could you *please* post actual code; you are using `ID` and `subject` interchangeably now, while you had a `gender` vs `Gender` typo before. It's very difficult to provide concrete advice when what you post has inconsistencies like this - you wouldn't believe the number of questions we get where the problem is an overlooked typo.

Comment: You don't *need* a correlation structure but you can't ignore residual temporal autocorrelation which you almost surely have if you model `Timepoint` a linear parametric term as you did in the `gamm4` model you asking about. There are many ways to model the temporal dependence, the correlation structure in the residuals (GLS style) or working correlation matrix (GEE style) are but two. The other would be to use flexible enough smooths per subject to model the temporal dependence directly. Whether you can do any of these depends on the data, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first model fails because you ask for too many coefficients; you ask for `Subject` specific intercepts *twice* (!) and try to fit 9 basis functions per `subject` in the `s(Timepoint, Subject, bs = "fs")` term.

1. The `"fs"` smooth of `Timepoint` by `Subject` already contains a random intercept per `Subject`: you don't need to add another separate random intercept via the `s(Subject, bs = "re")` term. You're just trying to estimate an extra `nlevels(Subject)` parameters that are confounded with the `"fs"` terms random intercept parameters, and `nlevels(Subject)` of these parameters are going to be shrunk to 0.

   Whenever you include `"fs"` smooths, you typically don't need a separate random intercept for the grouping variable of the `"fs"` smooth.
2. Looking at your plot, in many case you <<9 observations per subject. Unless you have >>9 observations for other subjects you can't estimate 9 parameters per subject; you don't have the data to support such rich smooths.
3. The `s(Age, by = Gender, bs = "fs")` really isn't doing what you think it's doing. There's no grouping variable here (so this should arguably raise an error). This just needs to be `s(Age, by = Gender)`.
4. You compound the problem from 1. by adding *another* `nlevels(Subject) - 1` parameters for the `subject` term by estimated parametric effects. While we say you "have" to include the `by` variable as parametric effect, typically what we mean is you need to have something in the model for the group means of the factor `by` term(s). The random intercept in either the `s(Timepoint, Subject, bs = "fs")` smooth or the `s(Subject, bs = "re")` smooth would account for these group means of `Subject`; you don't need yet more terms.

Get rid of `Subject` from the parametric effects, drop the `Subject` random intercept, and think through how many parameters you can afford to expend on the subject-specific time curves (in the `"fs"` Timepoint` smooth).

Why do you estimate time curves by subjects as having the same wiggliness but age by subject curves are each allowed their own wiggliness? You now have to choose values for `nlevels(Subject)` extra smoothness parameters. It also doesn't make much philosophical sense to treat one as essentially random and the other fixed for the same grouping variable.

A much simpler model for the first case would be:

```r
m1 <- gam(Y ~ Gender + s(Age, by = Gender) +
            s(Timepoint, Subject, bs = "fs", k = 10), 
          data = DF,
          method = "REML")
```

and shift `k` smaller if you can't fit even this simpler model.

If you want subject-specific `Age` effects, you could add that to the model as so:

```r
m1a <- gam(Y ~ Gender + s(Age, by = Gender) +
             s(Timepoint, Subject, bs = "fs", k = 10) +
             s(Age, Subject, bs = "fs"), 
           data = DF,
           method = "REML")
```

but at this point we probably need to start thinking more carefully as you'd want to be sure you aren't estimating another `nlevels(Subject)` random intercepts and check what identifiability constraints are being applied here.

With the exception of considering an auto correlated process in the model (Frank's suggestion), a GAM such as the one I show above would be a reasonable starting point for modelling longitudinal data via a GAM.

You're never going to get a plot like the one you showed from the paper by using `smooth_estimates()`. This is evaluating the partial effect of each smooth, while the plot from the paper seems to be on the response scale (so it would include the intercept). You could achieve this, kind of, by just adding the correct parametric effects to the `est` column (and the upper and lower intervals), but you'd have to get the right parametric effects added to the right rows, and you would have too-narrow an interval because you aren't really including the uncertainties in those parametric effects into the std. error.

Beyond that, you can't just pass the object of `smooth_estimates()` to `ggplot()` and expect it to do anything useful. You returned values for *all* smooths in your model in the object `sm`, so *any* row with an `Age` value that isn't `NA` will end up getting plotted somehow.

Better would be to get predictions from your model for the scenarios you want. To do that you would be forced to write down what you actually want to achieve, not just tell us what you want it to look like that image (I'm not reading a paper's methods section just to intuit what you want to show and what the authors of that paper did to generate their plot).

You seem to want to plot estimates of Age by Gender at the population level. So you will want something like:

```r
new_df <- with(df,
    expand.grid(Subject = factor(levels(Subject)[1], levels = levels(Subject)),
                Age = gratia::seq_min_max(Age, n = 100),
                Gender = factor(levels(Gender), levels = levels(Gender)),
                Timepoint = median(Timepoint)))
```

where you are explicitly conditioning on the `Age` and `Gender` values, and we'll *exclude* the random smooth effects due to `Subject` and `Timepoint` and `Age` from my `m1a` (assuming you can fit that) by use of the `exclude` argument to `predict.gam()`.

Top get the predicted values use `gratia::fitted_values()` unless you want to do everything by hand yourself, in which case use `predict(m1a, new data = new_df, exclude = ...., se.fit = TRUE)` etc with `exclude` set as below:

```r
fv <- fitted_values(m1a, data = new_df,
                    exclude = c("s(Timepoint,Subject)",
                                "s(Age,Subject)"))
```

where the things we pass to `exclude` are the labels of the smooths that relate to `Subject` level that we want to ignore as you seem to want population level effects. You can get these labels from `gratia::smooths(m1a)` if you don't know how {mgcv} creates labels for it's smooths.

At this point you might want to rethink your model structure a bit to include population (Pedersen et al 2019 PeerJ call these "global" smooths) effects for `Timepoint` as the only thing account for `Timepoint` is a random smooth term. Even so, you'd still have to condition the predictions on the specified value of `Timepoint` (here I use the median time point but you can plug in whatever value works for you).

Your `gamm4()` makes similar mistakes (the `bs = "fs"` is redundant on the `s(Age, by = Gender, bs = "fs")` smooth and why do you now model time as a linear parametric effect of `Timepoint` when in the `gam` you had subject-specific random smooths of `Timepoint` for these effects? If you wanted this in the `gam()` why not the `gamm4()`?

These models are so flexible and there are so many options, one needs to restrain oneself from trying everything in a model because you think you need it. Think about the model (effects) you want fit, write it down in words, bullet point form. Then write out a model formula in R's notation that you think covers each bullet point. Then post that in your question if you want to know if this is a suitable model for your data.

Comment: Gavin would you mind expanding a bit on what correlation pattern is assumed by your `m1a`?

Comment: @FrankHarrell None, the observations conditional upon the model are assumed to be independent; it making the assumption that the curves from the `s(Timepoint, Subject, bs = "fs")` are sufficiently flexible to capture the temporal correlation in the observations. If they aren't one would need something additional to model the autocorrelation. This starts to get complicated though as a wiggly smooth can be viewed as autocorrelation so including both in the model can lead to identifiability issues. Seeing as the OP has so many other issues with their models `m1a` is a reasonable start.

Comment: Thanks Gavin.  Is this modeling subjects as fixed effects?  I can see that this would take care of certain correlation patterns, but requires estimation of a large number of parameters.

Comment: Is what modelling subjects? Frank is asking about correlation structures in the sense of his GLS/Markov process comment. Your model includes subject as a fixed effect which is redundant given the subject random intercepts (of which you have two lots) as per my post.